# Why seperate such interlinked and indispensable words so far apart in a sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

On BBC News, there was news about royal wedding preparations. During the coverage, the text at the bottom of the screen was as follows:

> "Rehearsals have taken place in Windsor for wedding."

When I read it, it seemed a little bit odd to see "...for wedding" at the very end of the sentence. The expression "For wedding" belongs to "Rehearsal", but it seems very much separated from what it is connected.

To sum up, why is it not

> "Rehearsals for wedding have......"?

Would it not have been the correct sentence structure, if they had not disconnected "Rehearsals" and "for wedding" so far apart?

Comment: An adverbial phrase of place can go in either place: Dogs run furiously in the afternoon on the commons. Dogs run furiously on the commons in the afternoon.

Answer (score 1):

It appears from your question that you’re talking about a “headline” that appeared as an overlay, not “captioning” that is trying to display all the words spoken (for the deaf or hard-of-hearing.)

## Headlines follow their own rules

Headlines are not sentences, and they have their own distinct rules that vary from place to place (even from one newspaper or channel to the next.)

**You should not attempt to learn English usage from headlines, nor expect headlines to follow other English rules of grammar!**

In TV news, Headine style can be used in stationary graphics that go with the story, or as part of a “news feed” that scrolls or “flaps” on the screen.   Here is a fictional example showing these types:

> [image: TV News Screen]
>   - user Nandhp, [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:News_Ticker_(OSM_en).jpg)

These headlines are sometimes called the [Crawl, the Ticker, or the Chyron](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/News_ticker) (named for a type of equipment in the TV industry.)  They will typically follow the **in-house style of the news organization.**

In your example:

> Rehearsals have taken place in Windsor for wedding.

This seems strange at first glance, but it’s pretty normal for TV news, **especially without the final period.**

If this is one of a sequence of messages, then it might be expected that the sentence emphasizes “Rehearsals” and “Windsor” (the **what** and **where**) if the audience already knows they are watching a story about the royal wedding (if this is the “why”, it can be at the end of the sentence).